# Can i nest two output statement in Java

Tags: java

Is this possible ?  possible means,  how to do it correctly?                                                         **System.out.println("System.out.println("")");**

Comment: What do you want this code to do?

Comment: Do you want to print *System.out.println("");*

Comment: you can do this, IF you want to print _System.out.println("")_ , but `System.out.println("System.out.println("")");` will give you error

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. `System.out.println()` return type is void.

```
public void println()
```

When you write

```
System.out.println("System.out.println("")");
```

Compiler treats that the content inside `""`  as `String` not the function.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` is not returning values(void) so you can't do something like you want here. BTW what is the purpose of doing this?

Again

```
System.out.println("System.out.println("")"); // this is not valid statement
```

you can write as follows

```
System.out.println("System.out.println(\"\")");
```

But out put is just

```
System.out.println("")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print `System.out.println("")` then do like this

```
System.out.println("System.out.println(\"\")");
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `System.out.println` is a void method. I'm not sure why you want to do that, just print one line after another.

Answer (score 0):

no it is not possible Please check these link to know how the "system.out.print()" works

http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/print-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want. What result do you want to achieve? How much effort do you want to put into it?
What do you mean under nesting? The answer is: *generally no, but if you really want, yes*.

```
class SOP { // SOP stands for system.out.println
   public static SOP p = new SOP();
   public String toString() {return "";}
   SOP p(Object... oo) {for(Object o : oo){System.out.print(o.toString());} return this;}
   SOP pl(Object... oo) {p(oo); return l();}
   SOP l() {System.out.println(); return this;}
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
    SOP.p.p("hello,").pl(" world!");
    SOP.p.p("What exactly do you mean under \"nesting\"?", SOP.p.p("Is this nesting?"));
    SOP.p.l();
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
$ javac A.java 
$ java A
hello, world!
Is this nesting?What exactly do you mean under "nesting"?
```

Have fun!

PS probably you want to write a program that prints itself.
In this case: the stuff in the quotes is not evaluated as Java code, and there's no way in java to do it... unless you call the compiler via a command of the underlying OS, provided that the compiler is there on the target platform.